# Replacing Colors in Gnuplot Heat Maps (pm3d map)

Tags: gnuplot

I have several files that I would like to plot in 2D without interpolation (i.e. a heat map). The data is in three columns (not as a matrix):

```
#Example data
0 0 1
0 1 -1
0 2 10

1 0 -2
1 1 -0.1
1 2 20
```

I am using the following commands (Version 4.4):

```
set pm3d map
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
plot "file" us 1:2:($3>=0?0:$3) notitle w image
```

which produces the following image:

[image]

However, what I would like is:

1. Ensure that all (column 3) values less than zero will follow the color palette
2. Ensure that all (column 3) values greater than or equal to zero are white
3. The color bar does not contain white

I want the image to look like this:

[image]

Note, that this is only an example. In my real data, the values that are greater than or equal to zero are dispersed throughout the data. I've been playing around with this all morning but have yet to come up with a solution. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by setting those values to `NaN`:

```
set view map
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
plot "file" us 1:2:($3>=0?NaN:$3) notitle w image
```

This method works only with some terminals (see the discussion at [Transparency for specific values in matrix using Gnuplot while preserving the palette?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25321213/2604213)): It works at least with `wxt`, `pdfcairo`, `pngcairo` and `png`. It does *not* work with at least `x11` and `postscript`.

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

Comment: I tried that but GNUPLOT chokes with "GNUPLOT (plot_image):  Visible pixel grid has a scan line longer than previous scan lines." I am using Version 4.4. Is there a solution for that version?

Comment: Which patchlevel? I just tested with 4.4.4 and it also worked fine, with 4.2.6 it doesn't. But there the colors of the NaN pixels are wrong, the command is ok. Note, that I used `set view map`, `pm3d` must *not* be used!

Comment: Patch level 3. The NaN pixels end up being blue instead of white.

Comment: The "NEWS" for 4.4.4 compared to 4.4.3 contains the line "FIX NaN (not a number) implementation for Windows build". Maybe that is the relevant change. At the moment I don't know an other solution.

Comment: I will wait a bit to see if anybody else has a solution. If not, I will definitely accept your answer! Thanks again.

Comment: I've tried this with 4.6.0 (on another machine with it installed) and the NaN pixels are still colored blue instead of white

Comment: Strange, there is even a demo which shows this in `demo/imageNaN.dem`. The result with 4.6.0 on Linux with the pngcairo terminal is http://i.stack.imgur.com/fXuhu.png (with the same result for 4.4.4).

Comment: Is there some way to set them to white but not have white show up in the color bar?

Comment: Tweaking the palette like this: set pal defined (1 '#00008f', 8 '#0000ff', 24 '#00ffff', 40 '#ffff00', 56 '#ff0000', 63.9 '#800000', 64 '#FFFFFF') will add a white color at the max of the palette that is 'almost' invisible when the colorbox is drawn. Replace nan by the (exact) max value of the palette

Comment: I just tried this on 4.6.5 with the same result (blue pixels instead of white). I will trying tweaking the palette as described

Comment: It's quite hard to say whats happening: Which OS do you have, Windows? Do you run exactly the script which I posted?