# Transparency for specific values in matrix using Gnuplot while preserving the palette?

Tags: plot, undefined, gnuplot, transparency, alpha-transparency

Here's an interesting problem:

I have a 2D "matrix" of double-precision, binary data I'd like to plot using Gnuplot. This is easily done as follows:

```
plot "foo.dat" binary array=384x384 format='%double' with image
```

The trick is that certain "regions" of the data have a special value, say 1234567890.0. I want those elements to be fully transparent, and all other matrix entires to be fully opaque. Is there a way to set the transparency channel based on the data itself?

I have looked through the relevant parts of the Gnuplot documentation ([link](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.4/gnuplot.pdf)), and I think I need to use the `with rgbalpha` style, but I'm not sure how that applies or how to map the transparency correctly.

I have also looked at these examples ([link](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/rgbalpha.html)), but I'm not sure how I could apply it.

I wonder if this could be done in a one-liner (as above), or if it would need a couple lines (as when plotting contours on top of a binary matrix).

Thanks in advance!

***UPDATE***

I thought I'd give some examples for posterity. In all examples, I use the following preamble:

```
set title "Basic Plot"   # Or as appropriate
set size square
set palette @MATLAB   # see <http://www.gnuplotting.org/matlab-colorbar-with-gnuplot/>
set cbrange [-100000:100000]    # This cbrange fits my data well enough
                                # I would LOVE an automated way to do this!
val = 1234567890.0      # For missing data
```

My basic command produces the following:

```
plot "foo.dat" binary array=384x384 format='%double' with image
```

[image: Basic Plot]

I also tried what @Christoph suggested: replace values equal to `val` with `NaN`:

```
plot "foo.dat" binary array=384x384 format='%double' \
    using ($1 == val ? NaN : $1) with image
```

[image: Plot setting val to NaN]

I tried using `rgbalpha` in order to truly control transparency, and it produces the following:

```
plot "foo.dat" binary array=384x384 format='%double' \
    using 1:1:1:($1 == val ? 0 : 255) with rgbalpha
```

[image: Plot using rgbalpha]

***CONCLUSION***

The first two methods produce similar results. The first is bad because it messes up the colormap with false maxima. The first and second fall short in that they don't actually achieve transparency ("undefined" values in Gnuplot aren't automatically given transparency). The last is great in that it actually controls transparency, but it is in grayscale and doesn't use the `@MATLAB` palette as I want it to.

If somebody can cause all entries equal to `val` to be transparent *and* get the colormap to work correctly, I'll accept their answer.

***Where to go next****

The Gnuplot Documentation mentions the `set datafile missing` command ([link](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node172.html)). This looks promising, but it only seems to work for column-based data -- not binary files.

I imagine the best way to answer my original question is by setting up a set of functions to imitate a given palette for each "column" of the rgbalpha method -- something like this:

```
red(z)   = <stuff>
green(z) = <stuff>
blue(z)  = <stuff> 
plot "foo.dat" binary array=384x384 format='%double' \
    using red($1):green($1):blue($1):($1 == val ? 0 : 255) with rgbalpha
```

Bonus points if those functions somehow reference the current palette, so the specifics of a palette aren't hard-coded into these three functions.  :-)

Comment: The alpha channel goes from 0 to 255: 0 = fully transparent and 255 = fully opaque. When mapping your data into the transparency channel use the `using` option and an appropriate expression. For instance, in the example you link, `using 1:2:3:($3 == 1234567890 ? 0 : 255)` would set the transparency channel to 0 (transparent) if your data point equals 1234567890 and to 255 (opaque) if it doesn't.

Comment: Since it's binary data, there aren't three data columns, so that won't work. I think that's the right idea, but not quite there?

Comment: I don't know, why my answer doesn't work for you. I gave a similar answer in [Replacing Colors in Gnuplot Heat Maps (pm3d map)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22234147/2604213), were the NaN stuff also seemed not to work. I tested my script with the `png`, `pngcairo` and `wxt` terminals with gnuplot 4.6.5 both on Windows and Linux, and it always worked fine.

Comment: Using the `rgbalpha` style should also work fine, but the coloring becomes much more involved since you must 1) define the color functions yourself (which I have somewhere), 2) do the scaling yourself (use `stats` and also here remove the undefined values) 3) Use multiplot in case you need to show the colorbox. That all can be done, but is quite lengthy. If you can provide an example data file, I can check if I can get the NaN stuff to work with this data file.

Comment: @Christoph: your answer didn't have correct syntax for a binary array, at least as it was originally stated. Your `1:2:...` syntax would probably work for ascii files with data arranged in columns. That's why I edited it. If you mean, "why I'm not satisfied with the results", I am content with what you said. The output I get shows a dark blue outline where the NaNs are (picture #2, above), but I'd like that blue to be transparent instead. (Perhaps it does get rendered as transparency when writing to PNG? I'm using X11.) 

I've tried using `stats`, but could not get it to work with binary data.

Comment: @Christoph Here's a link to the file: http://www.lpl.arizona.edu/~vriesema/files/foo.dat. Note that in this case, I believe the dimensions are actually 512x512 rather than 384x384.

Comment: Sorry, yes I was referring to the blue color which should be transparent. Right now I could reproduce that with the `x11` terminal (Linux, 4.6.5). Can you try out the `wxt` terminal?

Comment: @Christoph: the `wxt` terminal rendered it correctly! Thanks! (Funny how it's different for different terminals....)

Comment: Great. I'll edit my answer to show the script and the image I get with your data.

Comment: Thanks again! (I also realized that I may not have sent you the exact same data file I used to make the above images. It should look similar, however.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by giving the respective pixel a value of 'NaN':

```
value = 123456789.0
plot "foo.dat" binary array=384x384 format='%double' \
     using ($1 == val ? NaN : $1) with image
```

Note, that this depends on the selected terminal. It works at least with `wxt`, `pdfcairo`, `pngcairo` and `png`, and does *not* work with `x11` and `postscript`. I didn't test other terminals.

Here is a self-contained example. The background color is set to show that the pixel indeed is transparent and not white:

```
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
set isosamples 11
set samples 11
plot '++' using 1:2:($1 == 0.5 && $2 == 0.5 ? NaN : $1) with image
```

The result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]

Using your example data file, the following script works fine and gives a nice result:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,800
set output 'foo.png'
set size square

f(x)=1.5-4*abs(x)
set palette model RGB
set palette functions f(gray-0.75),f(gray-0.5),f(gray-0.25)

val = 1234567890.0

set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set cbrange [-10000:10000]
plot 'foo.dat' binary array=(512,512) format='%double' using ($1 == val ? NaN : $1) with image notitle
```

[image]

Comment: This definitely got me on the right track -- replacing values with NaN tells Gnuplot the values are undefined, which it then ignores. It doesn't quite work as you wrote it: binary files don't have "columns" (or rather, Gnuplot treats it as a single column), so your `using 1:2:<stuff>` should be `using <stuff>`.

Comment: I edited your answer to fix the issue I described in my last comment, and am about to accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you did with the palette, but it looks great! (Also, it isn't actually doing "true" transparency, but this is *entirely* sufficient for my purposes. :-)) Thanks again -- so much!

Comment: I did nothing special with the palette. I got the function of the jet palette from [gnuplotting.org](http://www.gnuplotting.org/matlab-colorbar-with-gnuplot/comment-page-1/#comment-38037). To have real transparency, you must use `set terminal pngcairo nobackground`, see [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lumtn.png).